# How to make Django template engine to render in memory templates?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, templates, django-templates

I am storing my templates in the database and I don't have any path to provide for the `template.render` method.

Is there any exposed method which accepts the template as a string?

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[Instantiate `Template`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-the-template-system) with the string to use as a template.

Comment: It's bad to have links that can/will die. Please update, or the answer below should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 83):

Based on the [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#overview) for using the template system:

```
from django.template import Template, Context

t = Template("My name is {{ my_name }}.")
c = Context({"my_name": "Adrian"})
t.render(c)
```

Answer (score 5):

In Django < 1.8:

```
from django.template.loader import get_template_from_string

tpl = Template(get_template_from_string("My name is {{ my_name }}."))
```

Comment: From the [Django 1.8 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading/#get-template-from-string): "Private API `get_template_from_string(template_code)` was removed in Django 1.8 because…"